# `@@{' is not allowed as a class variable name (SyntaxError) while using s3 gem + rails 4.1.5

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I know this type of question is already asked.

I use `s3` gem to upload my files in `s3` bucket. But after `s3` gem installation, when I start rails server it shows this error:

```
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223:in `class_eval': /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: `@@{' is not allowed as a class variable name (SyntaxError)
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: syntax error, unexpected $end
        unless defined? @@{:instance_writer=>true}
                          ^
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223:in `block in cattr_reader'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:222:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:222:in `cattr_reader'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:258:in `cattr_accessor'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache.rb:155:in `<class:Store>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache.rb:154:in `<module:Cache>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache.rb:14:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/cache.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jbuilder-2.2.5/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jbuilder-2.2.5/lib/jbuilder/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jbuilder-2.2.5/lib/jbuilder.rb:317:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/rick/rick/Projects/practice/sharebox/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know, how to solve this error? Should I try another gem?

Comment: Could you provide full trace error?

Comment: i have updated my question with full error @rockskull

Comment: Have you read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25878748/906511 ?

Comment: @rockskull I have got the solution. What i have did i installed aws-sdk gem.

Comment: @rockskull yup i have already read that.

Comment: Glad to hear that. So, update your question or post the answer so people with the same problem can see what was the solution. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah i just ran  into this issue and resolved. It is because AWS updated their gem to 2.0. If you update the gem to 2.0 different configuration is required according to this [article](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxFKSK2QJE6RPZ/Upcoming-Stable-Release-of-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby-Version-2) they posted.

If you want to using the version you had before, just change the Gemfile like below:

## Gemfile

gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue this morning. We already had this aws-sdk gem installed but it was updated to version 2 yesterday. It seems that version 2 doesn't fix this anymore so I advice to use last version 1 : 1.61.0